# Why do I get Error in na.fail.default(list(doc.class = c(3L, 1L...missing values in object

Tags: r

I'm a complete beginner in R and this is my first time to post on stackoverflow. Please be gentle:)

I try to learn R by following tutorials and practical examples, but got stuck on this one and don't know what I do wrong.

I try to follow the tutorial as posted [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/202711_8f3ddd24fc9a4a6594d31f5da6344dcc.html). But get the following error message half when I try to train the model:

```
Error in na.fail.default(list(doc.class = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  missing values in object
```

I hope someone can help me understand what is going on here? I inspected tdmTrain and it only contains `NA` values. I'm just not sure why and how to fix it.

This is the code up to the step where I get the error message.

```
library(NLP)
library(tm) 
library(caret) 

r8train <- read.table("r8-train-all-terms.txt", header=FALSE, sep='\t')
r8test <- read.table("r8-test-all-terms.txt", header=FALSE, sep='\t')

# rename variables
names(r8train) <- c("Class", "docText")
names(r8test) <- c("Class", "docText")

# convert the document text variable to character type
r8train$docText <- as.character(r8train$docText)
r8test$docText <- as.character(r8test$docText)

# create varible to denote if observation is train or test
r8train$train_test <- c("train")
r8test$train_test <- c("test")

# merge the train/test data
merged <- rbind(r8train, r8test)

# remove objects that are no longer needed 
remove(r8train, r8test)

merged <- merged[which(merged$Class %in% c("crude","money-fx","trade")),]

# drop unused levels in the response variable
merged$Class <- droplevels(merged$Class) 

# counts of each class in the train/test sets
table(merged$Class,merged$train_test)

# a vector source interprets each element of the vector as a document
sourceData <- VectorSource(merged$docText)

# create the corpus
corpus <- Corpus(sourceData)

# preprocess/clean the training corpus
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower)) # convert to lowercase
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers) # remove digits
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation) # remove punctuation
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace) # strip extra whitespace
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords('english')) # remove stopwords

# create term document matrix (tdm)
tdm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)

as.matrix(tdm)[10:20,200:210] # inspect a portion of the tdm

# create tf-idf weighted version of term document matrix
weightedtdm <- weightTfIdf(tdm)
as.matrix(weightedtdm)[10:20,200:210] # inspect same portion of the weighted tdm

# find frequent terms: terms that appear in at least "250" documents here, about 25% of the docs
findFreqTerms(tdm, 250)

# convert tdm's into data frames 
tdm <- as.data.frame(inspect(tdm))
weightedtdm <- as.data.frame(inspect(weightedtdm))

# split back into train and test sets
tdmTrain <- tdm[which(merged$train_test == "train"),]
weightedTDMtrain <- weightedtdm[which(merged$train_test == "train"),]

tdmTest <-  tdm[which(merged$train_test == "test"),]
weightedTDMtest <- weightedtdm[which(merged$train_test == "test"),]

# remove objects that are no longer needed to conserve memory
remove(tdm,weightedtdm)

# append document labels as last column
tdmTrain$doc.class <- merged$Class[which(merged$train_test == "train")]
tdmTest$doc.class <- merged$Class[which(merged$train_test == "test")]
weightedTDMtrain$doc.class <- merged$Class[which(merged$train_test == "train")]
weightedTDMtest$doc.class  <- merged$Class[which(merged$train_test == "test")]

# set resampling scheme
ctrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",number = 10, repeats = 3) #,classProbs=TRUE)

# fit a kNN model using the weighted (td-idf) term document matrix
# tuning parameter: K
set.seed(100)
knn.tfidf <- train(doc.class ~ ., data = weightedTDMtrain, method = "knn", trControl = ctrl) #, tuneLength = 20)
```

Comment: Nice try for a first question, may you add within the question the results of `dput(head(r8train, 10)` and the same for r8test  (after the load of the 2 files) and the output of `R.Version()` so we may try to reproduce the problem ?

Comment: I agree with @Tensibai that this is a fairly good first question (+1). "I inspected tdmTrain ..."   That is somewhat downstream. Did you inspect each object that you create leading up to that? At what point do you first get something unexpected?

Comment: Thank you @Tensibai. Will remember to post all info the info to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in this part of the code:

```
tdm <- as.data.frame(inspect(tdm))
weightedtdm <- as.data.frame(inspect(weightedtdm))

dim(weightedtdm) #returns rows and columns
   10 10
```

You never use this to create a data.frame out of a tdm. You only get the first 10 rows and 10 columns. Not all the data from the tdm.

You need to use:

```
tdm <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(tdm))
weightedtdm <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(weightedtdm))

dim(weightedtdm)
[1]  993 9243
```

Here you can see the enormous difference between the 2 ways.

Using the first weightedtdm will result in 700 NA values for all columns except doc.class when you run `weightedTDMtrain$doc.class <- merged$Class[which(merged$train_test == "train")]`
This is the reason why `train` returns the error message.

Using the second way will work and your `train` will start to run. (slowly because of the repeated cross validation.)

Comment: Thank you for the help. This worked and makes sense.